# Associate a database row with a logged in user

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating a website through Joomla (creating a module) that is a members only site.
When members log in, I would want them to see their points (think about it like an airline flyer points site) which are unique. I have stored the points in a table in the database.

I have two tables:
`#__users` (the basic user table)
`#__smiles_users` (this stores the username, points etc etc)

Both tables have one similar column and this is "username".

I thought it would be wise to do it like this in an MYSQL query.

Connect to MYSQL
Find out the username that is logged in through #__users
Find the matching username in #__smiles_users table
Echo results that are in that specific row (that contains the correct username)

I have connected to MYSQL, echo the results, but I had to specify the WHERE function.

Comment: That's a nice story. Care to elaborate your issue or problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `#` character isn't allowed in table names (`#` starts a comment in SQL). Also, why are your table names prefixed with two underscores?

Comment: #__ In joomla, when you query a table, you start it with #__

Comment: My Question is:
A person logs into the site. They need to see their points. What code do I need that finds out who is logged into the site.
I want a value in my hands that tells me the username of the person that is logged into the site so I can locate his points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main approaches to accomplish this:

1. You can perform two separate queries for every table and join them via a `PHP` associative array:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `__users` WHERE `username` = ?
   ```

   And store the result to a var:

   ```
   $user = $result->fetch();
   ```

   Then do a second query for the remaining data of such user:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `__simles_users` WHERE `username` = ?
   ```

   And join the data programatically like this:

   ```
   $user_smiles_data = $result->fetch();
   foreach($user_smiles_data as $key => $value) {
       $user[$key] = $value;
   }
   ```
2. Or something like this if you don't want to perform two different queries:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `__users`
   INNER JOIN `__smiles_users`
   ON `__users`.`username` = `__smiles_users`.`username`
   ```

   This merges both tables by the `username` field *at query time*. The result will include all the fields of the two tables on a single row for the same `username`.

Comment: Hi arielnmz. Thank you for the swift reply. I understand your answer and I believe this would be a great way to go when it comes to "merging the tables together".
Correct me if I am wrong. But does the above code define which user in logged into the site?

Comment: You should then add a column on any table that defines the `logged` state and query for the `username` and the logged state you want. If you can't do that then you need another approach to first know wether an user is logged in or not and its `username`.

Comment: I have been doing some more research, would a $_SESSION be a better alternative to this? You have answered my question when it comes to linking the tables together. But I feel that if I had a "logged" column, at times if 2 people are logged in it might screw up?

Comment: Yes, you can merge both approaches, for instance, you can store the user's username on the php `$_SESSION` var and use it to query for the proper username and retrieve the user's data from the database. And another column won't screw your query if you retrieve and use your data correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably going to want to create a foreign key from one table to the other.

For example in SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE #__smiles_users
ADD FOREIGN KEY (username)
REFERENCES #__users(username)
```

This creates a link from one table to the other to ensure data integrity.

Comment: While you are correct in your statement, the original question (as it stands) is really unclear in what is trying to be achieved and isn't really an answer, better off in the comments section until the asker clarifies.

Comment: Hi ktbird. Even though this does not answer the question. It has sparked up an idea on something else I am working on. Thanks

Comment: I agree Scott but I am not able to comment. Happy to help Marc.

Comment: @ScottMcGready I think the fact that the OP's question isn't clear doesn't make an answer deserve a downvote.

Comment: @arielnmz as per the rules, it doesn't answer the question and therefore deserves a down vote. Bear in mind these questions will be archived for others who are searching for answers.

Comment: @ScottMcGready The question is *what question should it answer?*. The OP didn't even asked a direct question, so it's open to any suggestions, and as the OP himself stated, this actualed helped him. So as per the rules, I don't think the answer is, in fact, not useful and as the downvote's hint actually suggests, it's meant for *not useful* questions, not only the ones that don't actually answer the question. Refer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers) on meta for more information.